# Low-cost PCI Remote Management Adapter

Tags: remote, pci

I'm looking for a product similar to the Dell DRAC that can give low-level access to a PC from a remote location, i.e. access the BIOS, reboot the PC, etc. These are common in servers, but I have yet to find a simple, relatively low cost PCI adapter to accomplish this with a standard PC. Manufacturer-specific cards like this can be found on eBay, but I doubt they'd work in a normal PC.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to check out [Remotely turning on or rebooting a frozen computer](http://superuser.com/questions/319859/remotely-turning-on-or-rebooting-a-frozen-computer)

Answer (score 2):

> Manufacturer-specific cards

The reason they're manufacturer-specific is because they need to co-operate with the motherboard for a lot of low level tasks, like accessing the BIOS and rebooting the PC.

If you do find a generic one, I don't know if it will be cheap.

techi007 has the right idea, look at Intel's AMT or AMD's DASH and see if that fits your bill. Otherwise you're probably SOL.

Comment: Those cards **do** exist, though they are difficult to get. An example is the Raritan eRic G4.