# How do I determine if my server is AMT capable for remotely turning on or rebooting a frozen computer

Tags: remote, reboot

I just finished reading the subject post [Remotely turning on or rebooting a frozen computer](https://superuser.com/q/319859/60317) and have further questions.

I'm very interested in remote access to my server, in particular restarting it when it is in a stalled or blue-screen state.

How can I determine if my server is AMT enabled? It has a [GIGABYTE GA-Z68MA-D2H-B3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3855#ov) Motherboard and Intel Core i5-2500K CPU.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enabled, as AMT is only for vPro processors from Intel (see [here](http://www.intel.com/cd/channel/reseller/apac/eng/vpro/index.htm?prn) for the list) and yours is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel [Z68](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/z68-express-chipset.html) is a desktop/Gaming chipset and does not appear to support AMT. You might look at adding a board that allows Lights Out management but likley not inexpensive.  Any I have seen are from server vendors like Dell, HP and IBM/Lenovo and are often itegrated now.