# Ways to remotely reboot a Linux system

Tags: linux, debian, remote, reboot

I had a remote server running Debian *Sarge* that experienced some HDD failure and I meant to reboot it hoping that fsck could repair the errors automatically. I eventually drove out there and replaced the faulty disks...

But I was wondering: What other ways are there to force a Linux system to reboot that do not require hard drive access?

What I had tried:

- `shutdown -r now` Did not work, as `shutdown` is a program that would have to be loaded from disk, the error shown in the terminal was `bash: /sbin/shutdown: Input/output error`
- `init 6` same as above
- `telinit q` same as above
- `kill -2 1` This did *not* print an error, but did not work either. (However, it is possible that the Sarge init did not implement `SIGINT`, the sarge manpages did not mention it. So it could work in a more recent version of Debian)
- [This guide on PCFreak.net](http://pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-reboot-remotely-linux-server-if-reboot-shutdown-and-init-commands-are-not-working-sbinreboot-inputoutput-error-reboot-linux-in-emergency-using-magicsysrq-kernel-sysctl-variable/). However, this failed at `sysctl`, which was not in memory either.

Comment: Alt + SysRq + B -- This is basically the last ditch effort to force a reboot of a hung system.

Comment: 'Rebooting without accessing the HDD' - wow, weird one. Every time I think of a solution I end up hitting the HDD. The only real 'give' you've got is if there are any ramdisks to play with.

Comment: @jmreicha - that won't work over SSH, that'd reboot your local machine!

Comment: Yes you're right, heh, I should have mentioned you have to have local access to do this.

Comment: @PhonicUK If you're working with a remote system, I hope you've got a KVM available, and from there you could remotely press those keys :) Which, that's how you remotely reboot a system that has a misconfigured network stack. Let's not go into details why I know this. >.>

Comment: Found this, it is basically the keyboard combo through command prompt.  http://rackerhacker.com/2009/01/29/linux-emergency-reboot-or-shutdown-with-magic-commands/.

Comment: @jmreicha This seems to be the same as the guide on PCFreak.net, for which I had to enable the kernel `sysrq` capabilities with `sysctl` ... which sadly is a program and not a builtin. Though I have to admit now, that I did not really check whether `sysrq` was already enabled

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remotely turning on or rebooting a frozen computer](http://superuser.com/questions/319859/remotely-turning-on-or-rebooting-a-frozen-computer)

Comment: @techie007 I totally forgot about this question, sorry; No I don't think that is a duplicate, though it is similar. The question was about what you can do after things messed up, not before. However I found that in current Debian versions `init` is always in memory and thus `init 6` would work. Not sure if it's possible for `init` to be paged now

Answer (score 3):

You mention it is a remote server...Which means it is a prime candidate for a ILO, DRAC etc.

Check the documentation to see if such a card is installed.

If it is you can connect to the OS on that card and remotely take over the keyboard, screen and **powerswitch** etc without even touching the main OS.  Thus you can do a hard reboot, and keep (remotely) watching the screen as your server runs though BIOS, boot and fsck.

If it is not installed and it is a significant distant to drive to it I really recommend adding such a card or installing some other remote KVM connection.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no solutions for rebooting without having a harddisc connected or the necessary software loaded on ramdisk. If it's a virtual machine, reboot it on the hypervisor. Otherwise I hope you have a PDU / IPMI or similar.

Comment: The question is about ways to remotely reboot a Linux system, not to resolve a (already resolved) situation.